# timezone issue on query druid data with avatica sql

Tags: druid, apache-calcite

I'm using avatica as DB Driver of druid.
I inserted one row with 'time' column  "2017-09-28T18:00:00.000.Z", but the data stored in druid is "2017-09-28T10:00:00.000.Z" (in UTC time), my question is how can i query out this record with UTC+8 timezone ?

Comment: I tried to set <code>spring.druid.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Hongkong</code>,  but got 404 error:   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Failed to execute HTTP Request, got HTTP/404

Answer (score 0):

See "sqlTimeZone" on http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/sql.html. You can set it as a JDBC connection property (pass it in the properties parameter to DriverManager.getConnection, or use your framework's ability to set connection properties).